# Slicing pandas dataframe by closest value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
        age      score
5        72      99.424
6        70      99.441
7        69      99.442
8        67      99.443
9        71      99.448

mean score: 99.4396
```

The mean is the mean over all `score` column. How can I slice/get an `age` value that is say +/-  0.001 closer to the mean score.

So in this case: 67 and 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
mean = df['score'].mean()
df[df['score'].between(mean - .001, mean + .001)]['age']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics
df = pd.DataFrame({"age": [72, 70, 69, 67, 71], "score": (99.424, 99.441, 99.442, 99.443, 99.448)})
df["diff"] = abs(df["score"] - statistics.mean(list(df["score"])))
```

You get :

```
   age   score    diff
0   72  99.424  0.0156
1   70  99.441  0.0014
2   69  99.442  0.0024
3   67  99.443  0.0034
4   71  99.448  0.0084
```

Then :

```
x = 0.002
ages = list(df.loc[df["diff"] < x]["age"])
[Out]: [70]
```

x will be your parameter for the difference with the mean.

EDIT: we cannot get the same result as you as we do not have your whole score column by the way